# Is someone able to enable an existing deploy key for a repo using terraform?

Tags: gitlab, terraform

```
resource "gitlab_project" "project" {
  name             = "${var.repo_name}"
  description      = "${var.repo_description}"
  visibility_level = "${var.visibility_level}"
  namespace_id     = "${var.namespace_id}"
}
```

I am not sure what to do with the new resource here.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/gitlab/r/deploy_key.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently [`gitlab_deploy_key`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/gitlab/r/deploy_key.html) resources don't appear to support [importing](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) but is [being developed](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-gitlab/issues/36), although not very quickly. In addition, the [Gitlab Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/gitlab/index.htm) also lacks [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html). So, unfortunately, right now it appears you can't use an existing deploy key.

You could create a new key, see how the state file is formatted, and then manually import your existing key by directly manipulating the state file. While this [**isn't** normally recommended](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/#inspection-and-modification) it may be your only choice until the provider is more fully featured.